# How to not get changed-signals to be emitted when setting the current-index in QAbstactItemView?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qabstractitemview

I'm programmatically changing the selected item with `setCurrentIndex()` of my Tree- and TableViews.

If the current item has changed, a multitude of signals are emitted (`currentChanged()`, `currentColumnChanged`, etc).

I'm listening to some of these signals in order to be informed when the user changes the selection.

Is there a way/a signal to distinguish between user-selected and programmatically selected events?

I tried using the `activated()`-signal on the views, but this seems to not behave the same way on different platforms (sometimes activated is triggered only if double-clicked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you could just block all signals while making your change?
[QSignalBlocker](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html) or [QObject::blockSignals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals) could help:

```
{
    const QSignalBlocker blocker(myWidget);
    myWidget->setCurrentIndex(someIndex);
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but you have to block signals on the view's `selectionModel()`, not on the view itself.

Comment: Actually, after some testing, this breaks the GUI functionality, blocking Signal in the view or in the selectModel is not the best way.

Comment: @PatrickB., that's actually strange, are you unblocking the signal right after the change? Maybe some update / invalidate / `emit layoutChanged()` could help? What confuses me is that smth else in GUI breaks because of blocking selection or index. You could use `disconnect + connect` but that would be even more of a trick, imho

Comment: This symptoms are that the GUI-representation of, e.g. the tableview gets messed up when quickly selecting columns/rows.  Because signals are getting scheduled while the previous signals are not yet finished. During that blockSignals() is still true. Or at least that is my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What I finally did, and it works in my case because I have a single-thread application, I created a custom variable `programmatic-select`, which I set to true before calling `setCurrentIndex()`. In the `changeSelection()`-slot I check this variable and do nothing if it is true.

Very important for this to work is to connect the slot to the signal with the connection-type `DirectConnection`. In this case the slot is executed synchronously when the signal is emitted and I'm sure the value of my variable is safe.

Answer (score 0):

In your slot, you can use QObject::sender() to return the QObject to you. From there, there are a handful of ways you should be able to distinguish the source.

Comment: In both cases (user selection, programmatic selection), the sender is the view or the selectionModel.

Comment: The programmatic events you speak of - are they things like timers, etc? If so, you could use QObject::isWidgetType() on the object returned by QObject::sender(). You might also look at QObject::senderSignalIndex() -- I've never used that one, but it seems to be for cases like yours.

Comment: Working with the sender is tedious, unfortunately and leads to nothing. What I'm trying to to do is to workaround a Qt feature, and this is not intended. Thanks for your insights, though. I have a solution which works.